# IE6 Selectors issues

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

My site actually works okay in other browsers but when I checked in IE6, there is a problem. In my global navigation, I clicked this certain page. For example, I clicked ABOUT ME page. My global navigation changes its image when the page is active. Like it has a different color from inactive pages. In IE6, when I'm in the current page, ABOUT ME, the current image in the global navigation is different. Say, it's CONTACT US. But when hovered, the image that appears is correct.

This is the snippet of CSS:

```
    .cat-item-5 {

    float: left;

    display: inline;

    width: 162px;

    height: 48px;

    text-indent: -30000px;

    background: -639px 0 url(images/menu.png) no-repeat;

}



.cat-item-5 a {

    display: block;

    width: 162px;

    height: 48px;

    background: -639px 0 url(images/menu.png) no-repeat;

}



.cat-item-5 a:hover,

.cat-item-5.current-cat a {

    background: -639px 0 url(images/menu_o.png) no-repeat;

}
```

Hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: can you fiddle this with html code as well

Comment: IE6 did never support chaining selectors. I.e. in `.cat-item-5.current-cat` it reads only `.cat-item-5`, not `.current-cat`.

Comment: so how will I construct it for IE6 to read?

Comment: This is a wordpress site by the way.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to support IE6? The best suggestion I can give is to stop supporting it. I you *really* have to keep supporting it, you'll need to have an extra class on the relevant elements, and apply the style to that class instead of the double-class selector you have now.

Comment: Hey Spudley! Thank you very much for your advice! It is actually working correctly in all browsers. I just gave it a unique class name. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you solved it. I would still recommend dropping IE6 support if possible; most devs I know don't even support IE7 any more today in 2013, let alone IE6. More importantly, Microsoft's support for IE6 ends early next year, after which there will be no more security patches. Anyone still on IE6 then will almost certainly get hacked soon afterward (if they haven't been already), so if you have clients who are insisting on sticking with it, you need to be warning them strongly that they need to upgrade urgently.

Comment: As long as developers keep supporting IE6 it will never die. Lets all do this world some justice and put IE6 to rest.

Answer (score 2):

IE6 has really *really* bad CSS support. It also has some nasty little bugs, of which you've been tripped up by one.

The bug is that when you have a double-class selector like `.cat-item-5.current-cat`, IE6 will only see the first of those classes, so it acts as if the selector is just `.cat-item-5`.

There's no good way around this bug. The only solution is to add another class to the relevant elements, and select that instead.

Your only other option is to simply drop support for IE6.